# How to create a simple vertical menu in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Excuse me for the simple question, I've read a Bootstrap book but it merely scrached the surface of this library and I've also searched google but the great majority of the results show how to build complex horizontal menus.

I want to create old-fashioned vertical menu, no pills or whatever, one that has menu itens that fill 100% the horizontal space and stack on top of each other. I am not concerned about mobile devices because I am going to hide it in ex small and maybe in small devices. I want this:

```
|menu item      | the menu item and the menu have the same bondaries.
|menu item 2    |
|menu item 3    |
```

I am trying this:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li   class="active"><a  href="imoveisvenda.html"> imoveis a venda <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li class="active">{!!  link_to_route('rota', 'imóveis locação') !!}</li>
<nav>
</div>
```

I get menu itens that appears pills (they don't fill 100% of horizontal space) and the menu items are bigger than I want. The code above gives me this:

```
||menu item|   |  the menu item doesn't fill space available for the menu.
||menu|        |
```

Another doubt I have is if there's a class to make the menu itens more compact - by more compact I mean decrease the top and bottom padding that bootstrap applies to the menu itens.

Comment: What you want menu or tab? Please clarify.

Comment: I want a menu. I specified at the title and throughtout the question body.